# Embed twitter feed with images

Tags: image, rss, twitter, embed

When embedding a twitter feed - what's the best way (if any) to display the image referenced in a tweet directly - not as a link to e.g. Twitpic? The image should be displayed as img, like in a blog post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn on [entities](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities) for the statuses so that Twitter automatically parses URLs for you. Then  use [Embedly](http://embed.ly/) to build the image embed code.

Comment: Isn't there a way in jquery/json to do this without any paid service(like embedly)?

Comment: Embedly has a free tier. You could do it on your own but you would have to manually build a list of services and the code to use for embedding each type of content.